# How do I install the full Compiz fusion plugin set?

Tags: installation, command-line

What is the install command to issue to the terminal to install compizfusion ( the full package set )

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-main compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
```